# Bash customization only take place after interacting with the terminal for the first time

Tags: bash, terminal

sorry for the title, I have no better way to convey what is occurring to me. The situation is the following, I am using `bash`, `wezterm`(terminal emulator) and [`starship`](https://starship.rs/) (customizable prompt). But for some reason, every time I open a new terminal, it is always the stock/ default prompt, and I have to press enter or type something for it to pickup the updates. I have no idea what kind of behavior is happening here

[image: image of terminal showing the problem]

As you can see, the first line is the line that has no styling applied, while the second line is how its supposed to look.

My observations are the following

1. This always happens when opening a new terminal
2. This does not seem to happen when I ssh into this machine
3. This does not happen when I open a new terminal inside a terminal via multiplexer like [`zellij`](https://zellij.dev/)

The weird thing is, that it works properly after typing anything. This is why I have no idea how to debug this. There is probably something weird happening that I am not aware of how it works.

My bash setup can be [found here](https://github.com/Nikola-Milovic/.dotfiles/tree/master/bash), but I'll outline the most important files here

my `bash_profile` which just sources my `.bash_rc`

```bash
source ~/.bashrc
```

My `.bashrc`

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples
# If not running interactively, don't do anything

if [ -e ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    source ~/.bash_aliases >/dev/null 2>&1
fi

case $- in
*i*) ;;
*) return ;;
esac

.. truncated, other stuff is the default that comes in bashrc basically
```

And finally my `.bash_aliases`

```bash
unalias -a
set -o vi
...

# Have to install bash-preexec as well
[[ -e ~/.bash-preexec.sh ]] && source ~/.bash-preexec.sh

# here are the evals and they are 100% evaluated
source ~/.config/wezterm/wezterm.sh
eval "$(starship init bash)"

[[ -e ~/.config/personal/bash/alias_personal ]] && \. ~/.config/personal/bash/alias_personal
```

This also might be an issue with the library itself, but I highly doubt this. This behavior started occurring after I was fiddling with my config, its been months now.

Comment: `echo "$PROMPT_COMMAND"` please

Comment: First, [please do not post images of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text). Next, since you are sourcing another file and running an `eval` on the command (don't get me started on that), we do need to see what you are sourcing.

Comment: have you tried it with another terminal emulator? my guess is thats the cause

Comment: @doneal24 this is not an "image of code" but an screenshot of an application, the app he is having trouble with.

Comment: @ChrisDavies thanks for that comment, it led me into the right direction. Something about `bash-preexec.sh` was interacting with the `starships` preexec. Removing it temporarily fixes the issue. I'll look into their respecting repositories.
@Junaga Its happening in every terminal, since they're all based on this config

Comment: @doneal24 This is an appropriate usage of an image I believe, since the problem is visual and I had to show it. The code for the issue is also provided, alongside my entire config in the github. But I don't want to force anyone to go through that mess so I truncated and kept the most important parts (what I believed to be important). And why not get started with `eval`? I absolutely have no idea why that would be a problem, explaining that could be helpful

Comment: @Junaga A terminal emulator that does not allow for text to be copied to the clipboard sounds unusual. You can call any terminal emulator, text editor, etc. an application but the general consensus on U&L is that you need to cut & paste if it is possible to do so. Also, my comment did not use the phrase "an image of code" nor did the link I pointed to so I am not sure what you are referring to by that.

Answer (score 1):

Starship applies its configuration each time you execute *any* command (see [starship init bash --full-code-print](https://gist.github.com/tsuyoshicho/d7f84c8add154c51247387d57cee4de5) for one example of it setting up `$PROMPT_COMMAND`) but as far as I can see not in the `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile`. Aside from the incredible inefficiency this incurs, it also means that the prompt cannot be set until you execute a command. A null command (i.e. hitting enter by itself) is acceptable here, but the point is that you need to do something.

It is how it is.

Personally, if all I wanted was a fancy prompt then I'd set that directly in `~/.bashrc` (and have `~/.bash_profile` call it on login).